# Gradle calling commandLine multiple times - only last one runs

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to chmod +w an entire directory. I need to modify it and it's expected to be read-only, as it is managed by perforce configuration management system.

My code seems to run properly:

```
String path = projectDir.toString() + '/src/main/java/com/<snip>'

task chmod(type:Exec) {
   println("chmoding all in $path")

   FileTree  javaFiles = fileTree(path)
   javaFiles.each { File javaFile ->
      String filename = path + "/" + javaFile.name
      commandLine 'chmod', 'a+w', filename
      println "Chmoding $filename"
   }
}
```

The printed path is the right one, but only the last iteration is actually chmoded. I tried moving the commandLine above the println, thinking I'll try shotgun debugging but to no avail.

One alternative I tried is to run commandLine once with

```
commandLine 'bash', 'chmod', 'a+w', '/src/main/java/com/<snip>/*'
```

but it also failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Exec` task executes once, not multiple times. You are calling `Exec.setCommandLine(...)` multiple times in the configuration phase. When the Exec task executes (in the execution phase) it simply executes the last one.

You probably want to call `Project.exec(...)` multiple times.

Eg:

```
ext {
    path = 'src/main/java/com/<snip>'
}
task chmod {
    inputs.dir path
    doLast {
        fileTree(path).each { File javaFile ->
            exec {
                println "Chmoding $javaFile"
                commandLine 'chmod', 'a+w', javaFile.absolutePath
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it through one command, try

```
commandLine 'bash', 'chmod', '-R', 'a+w', '/src/main/java/com/<snip>'
```

Comment: I actually tried something similar and got an error. I figured the other route was easier. -R on the directory would probably work for me without calling bash. I originally used bash to do wildcard expansion.